# Querying from list of related in SQLalchemy and Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have `User` which `has-one` `Person`. So `User.person` is a `Person`. 
I am trying to get a list of `User` from a list of `Person`.

I tried the following:

```
>>> people = Person.query.filter().limit(3)
<flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x111c69bd0>

>>> User.query.filter(User.person.in_(people)).all()
NotImplementedError: in_() not yet supported for relationships.  For a simple many-to-one, use in_() against the set of foreign key values.
```

What is the best way to get a list of `User`s where `User.person` is in that list of `people`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the error message helpfully tells you, you need to use `in_` against the foreign keys instead:

```
User.query.join(User.person).filter(Person.id.in_(p.id for p in people)).all()
```

Since you're going to query for both anyway, might be better to do a joined load and then get the people using Python:

```
people = Person.query.join(Person.user).options(db.contains_eager(Person.user)).limit(3).all()
users = [p.user for p in people]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the generator with `or_`:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_
people = Person.query.filter().limit(3)
cond = or_(*[User.person == person for person in people])
User.query.filter(cond).all()
```

This can be useful when you try to request records with filter of objects that have already been received, such as statuses.