# SQLAlchemy relationships: Find instances that have one or more attribute in common

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm not sure how to phrase this question, as I don't know the terminology around what it is I'm trying to achieve (mods, please feel free to suggest improvments).

I have two types of users, `Student` and `Instructor`. Both can have one or more `Tag`s, which are basically a genre (rock, funk, etc). To associate `Student` and `Instructor` with a `Tag` I have an association table for each.

I have a last model, `Lesson` that have IDs for `Student` and `Instructor`. At the creation of a `Lesson`, only one of these IDs are set, depending on whether it´s a `Student` or an `Instructor` that creates it. If a `Student` creates a `Lesson`, I need to find all `Instructor`s that have one or more `Tag`s in common with the `Student`. How do I go about achieving this? I have a limited knowledge about database relationships, so any help is appreciated!

Here's the code for the models:

```
class Instructor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    genres = db.relationship("Tag", secondary=instructor_tag_association_table, backref=db.backref("instructors", lazy="dynamic"))

class Student(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    genres = db.relationship("Tag", secondary=student_tag_association_table, backref=db.backref("students", lazy="dynamic"))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    genre = db.Column(db.String)

class Lesson(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    instructor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("instructor.id"))
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("student.id"))

# Association tables
instructor_tag_association_table = db.Table(
    "instructor_tags",
    db.Column("instructor_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("instructor.id")),
    db.Column("tag_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id")),
)
student_tag_association_table = db.Table(
    "student_tags",
    db.Column("student_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("student.id")),
    db.Column("tag_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tag.id")),
)
```

I know this is wrong on several levels, but say I have the ID of a single `Instructor`, then I'm looking for a query like this to find lessons:

```
instructor_id = 1
instructor = Instructor.query.filter_by(id=instructor_id).first()
eligible_lessons = Lesson.query.filter(Lesson.student_id.has("genre in instructor.genre"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436231/6560549) one.

If I've interpreted correctly, I think the crux of the problem is that you are looking for lessons that have a student but no instructor assigned, where there is an intersection between the lesson's student `genres` and the instructor's `genres`.

I added `student` and `instructor` relationships on your `Lesson` model to complement the `Foreign Keys` you already have created, which made it easier for me to generate some testing data if nothing else:

```
class Lesson(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    instructor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("instructor.id"))
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("student.id"))
    student = db.relationship(Student, uselist=False, backref='lessons')
    instructor = db.relationship(Instructor, uselist=False, backref='lessons')
```

Here's the testing data I generated:

```
import random

db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
# create a set of tags
tags = [Tag(genre=g) for g in ('Jazz', 'Funk', 'Rock', 'Classical', 'Metal')]
# create 10 students with 2 tags randomly assigned
students = [Student(genres=random.sample(tags, 2)) for _ in range(10)]
# create 2 instructors with 2 tags randomly assigned
instructors = [Instructor(genres=random.sample(tags, 2)) for _ in range(2)]
# create a lesson for each student
lessons = [Lesson(student=s) for s in students]
db.session.add_all(tags + students + instructors + lessons)
db.session.commit()
```

Then for the query, I queried `Lesson` joining on `Student` and `student_tag_association_table` so that I could find a `Lesson` with `instructor_id == None` and a `Student` with a `tag_id` that matches one of the `Instructor's` linked `tag_ids`:

```
# randomly select an instructor
instructor = random.choice(instructors)
possible_lessons = db.session.query(Lesson).\
    join(Student).\
    join(student_tag_association_table).\
    filter(and_(Lesson.instructor_id == None,
        or_(
            student_tag_association_table.c.tag_id.in_(
                g.id for g in instructor.genres
            )
        )
    )).all()
```

Then to test:

```
for lesson in possible_lessons:
    try:
        assert any([g in lesson.student.genres for g in instructor.genres])
    except AssertionError:
        print('uh oh')
    else:
        print('yes')

# yes
# yes
# yes
# yes
# yes
```

As the test data is random, you'll get a different number of `yes` outputs each time.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! May I ask you what the `c` is in `student_tag_association_table.c.tag_id`?

Comment: Sure, `c` is just how you access the `Columns` of a `Table`. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#accessing-tables-and-columns